# Saving to txt file linked list

Tags: c, file, linked-list

Okay, so here's my problem I'm trying to figure out how to write my singly linked list to file, not sure yet what should I use so I went with txt files and fprintf not sure if its good if somebody could tell which way would be better and explain would be great. Well back to my code I'm having problems saving to file basicaly my function saves items for 1st client but not for second one. What I did wrong? If rest of my code is neccessary I can post it but its like 500 lines.

```
struct item
{
    char item_name[30];
    char item_state[30];
    double item_price;
    char item_status[30];
    double item_price_if_not;
    struct item *next;
};
struct client
{
    char client_name[30];
    char client_last_name[30];
    struct item *item_data;
    struct client *next;
};




void savetxt(struct client *head)
{
    FILE *f;
 f = fopen("data.txt","w");
   if(f == NULL)
   {
       printf("error");
   }
    struct item *CurrentItem = head->item_data;
    while(head != NULL)
    {
        printf("try");
        fprintf(f,"%s\n",head->client_name);
        fprintf(f,"%s\n",head->client_last_name);
        while(CurrentItem != NULL)
        {
            printf("tryitem");
            fprintf(f,"%s\n",CurrentItem->item_name);
            fprintf(f,"%s\n",CurrentItem->item_state);
            fprintf(f,"%fp\n",CurrentItem->item_price);
            fprintf(f,"%s\n",CurrentItem->item_status);
            fprintf(f,"%fp\n",CurrentItem->item_price_if_not);
            CurrentItem = CurrentItem->next;
        }
        head = head->next;
        fprintf(f,"\n\n");
    }
    fclose(f);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Well there's no error like I said it saves client list but inner list for second client is not saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update `CurrentItem` at the end of the outer `while` loop, after you've set the new `head`:

```
...
head = head->next;
CurrentItem = head->item_data;
...
```

Otherwise, CurrentItem is used to scan the list of items for the first client and then never reset to the beginning of the items of the next client.

**EDIT**

It's actually better to set `CurrentItem` at the beginning of the `while` loop, otherwise when `head` is NULL `CurrentItem = head->item_data` will fail:

```
while (head != NULL) {
    CurrentItem = head->item_data;
    ...
}
```

Comment: When I added this part my function crashes after first loop. Are you sure that when I set at beginning  struct item *CurrentItem = head->item_data; can update it like so?

Comment: Sure. Check that head->item_data are properly set to NULL at the end of the list, etc. and then use `gdb`. Also, post a complete example with some data to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ah, clearly if `head` is NULL `CurrentItem` will try to access a NULL pointer. So you'd better move CurrentItem at the beginning of the while loop instead.

Comment: Okay got it working had to it this way         if(head != NULL)
{
          CurrentItem = head->item_data;
},thanks for help.